# LIRC (remote control daemon) doesn't work

Tags: xbmc, remote-control, lirc

I have Pinnacle's Analog TV PCI card with remote (IR) controller. I want to use this remote controller to control XBMC.

I've read that I need LIRC daemon so I installed it (*sudo apt-get install lirc*) and selected *Pinnacle Systems PCTV (pro) reciever* as *Remote control configuration* (during LIRC setup). For *IR transmitter* I selected *none* (AFAIK I don't have it). Now the problems arise (cut out):

```
Setting up lirc (0.9.0-0ubuntu1) ...
ls: cannot access /lib/modules/3.2.0-23-generic/kernel/drivers/staging/lirc: No such file or directory
 * Loading LIRC modules                                                  [ OK ] 
find: `/sys/class/rc/*/': No such file or directory
 * Starting remote control daemon(s) : LIRC                              [fail]
```

[Here](http://pastebin.com/XXHHLK63) is my /etc/lirc/hardware.conf. I've also tried [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=12072365&postcount=7) workaround

*sudo ln -s /lib/modules/3.2.0-23-generic/kernel/drivers/staging/media/lirc /lib/modules/3.2.0-23-generic/kernel/drivers/staging/lirc*

but it doesn't work.

How to make use of this remote control before I throw it out the window? :)

Answer (score 1):

I had an issue with a Harmony Remote not working correctly.  After walking round the internet for a few days, I came across this article on using `ir-keytable`.

After uninstalling LIRC, installing and configuring ir-keytable, I had the remote working as expected when running a trace using `ir-keytable -t`; however XMBC did not see the remote.  After resinstalling the LIRC packages, XBMC worked correctly with no further configuration.

I don't know if it will work for you, but could be worth a try...

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1754719